# Redirect in setTimeout to a location held in a variable outside current scope

Tags: javascript

I make an ajax request, and the JSON response, after parsing, gives me the link to the page I want to redirect the user to after 3 seconds.

I'm doing it this way:

```
response = JSON.parse(res);
var link = response.link;
setTimeout("window.location.href=link",3000);
```

However, I get an error message that `link` is not defined, presumably because it isn't in the scope of the setTimeout script.

How can I work around this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please don't use a string for setTimeout.

```
response = JSON.parse(res);
var link = response.link;

setTimeout(function ()
{
    window.location.href = link;

}, 3000);
```

Answer (score 1):

By using a closure (untested):

```
var aLink;

function getCallBack(link){
     return function(){
         window.location.href = link
     }
}

setTimeout(getCallBack(aLink),3000)
```